# A shortcut to get the point of previous frame plus its width?

Tags: objective-c

Many times when i am programing a UI ,  i have to put some view after the previous view, so to get the previous value i am calculating its x/y position ,add to this its width/height, and get the desired frame to the next view ,

```
newX=previous.frame.origin.x+previous.frame.size.width;
newy=previous.frame.origin.y+previous.frame.size.height;
```

Is there a short way to get that value of a view ,in one word ? 
When you have to do that many times , it becomes a real headache every time again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C functions declared in `CoreGraphic.h`:

```
newX = CGRectGetMaxX(previous.frame);
newy = CGRectGetMaxY(previous.frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a macro

```
#define NextX(frame) (frame.origin.x+frame.size.width)
#define NextY(frame) (frame.origin.y+frame.size.height)
```

and then you can use it like

```
newX=NextX(previous.frame);
newY=NextY(previous.frame);
```

Comment: You fogot () bracers. For NextX(previous.frame)/2.0 will be extended into: frame.origin.x+frame.size.width/2.0;